# is std::tuple required to use empty base class optimization?

Tags: c++

Will

```
std::is_empty<std::tuple<Args...>>::value
```

return true if every type in `Args` is empty? A quick test in gcc 4.9 indicates that this is the case but is it required by the standard?

Comment: Who says that `tuple` class even inherits from anything?

Comment: @jrok: No-one's saying that. The question is asking whether that's the case.

Comment: As far as I can read the standard, there seems to be no requirement on the tuple implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no requirement that `tuple` use inheritance to enable the empty base class optimisation.

The only textual specification of the tuple library is:

> This subclause describes the tuple library that provides a tuple type as the class template tuple that can
>   be instantiated with any number of arguments. Each template argument specifies the type of an element
>   in the tuple. Consequently, tuples are heterogeneous, fixed-size collections of values. An instantiation of
>   tuple with two arguments is similar to an instantiation of pair with the same two arguments.

with no mention of any implementation details; and the template specification begins:

```
template <class... Types>
class tuple {
```

not specifying that it must inherit from anything.

Comment: +1 I still feel like the question is a little odd but this is perfectly accurate answer.